# How to pipe multiline input to the Node.js program?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, stdout, stdin

I've built a `Node.js` program which basically takes a multiline input using [readline](https://github.com/maleck13/readline) module via `prompt`. Here's the code for the same

```
    let lineReader = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
      });

    lineReader.prompt();  

    let i = 0;
    let communityCards = [];
    let evalCards = [];

    lineReader.on('line', line => {

        console.log('line', line);
    });

    lineReader.on('close', ()=>resolve(evalCards));
```

Here's my multiline input

```
KS AD 3H 7C TD
John 9H 7S
Sam AC KH
Becky JD QC
```

It is working fine because it takes input from prompt upon running `node index.js` and outputs to `stdout` line by line but I want this multiline input passed to my program via piping via `stdin` and output to `stdout` upon hitting the `Enter`. Something like below:

```
$ multiline-input | node index.js
```

Can someone help me in figuring this out?

Answer (score 1):

This seems a rather shell related question.

If you qoute your multi-line input, it should work. Something like that:

```
$ echo 'KS AD 3H 7C TD
John 9H 7S
Sam AC KH
Becky JD QC' | node index.js
```

**EDIT**

As I understand your question now, you want to add each line read to the array `evalCards`, so just use the following handler:

```
lineReader.on('line', line => {
    evalCards.push(line)
})
```

Comment: Then I don't quite understand your question. Do you want to concatenate the lines to a single string instead of reading line by line?